# TypeError: num.bitLength is not a function

Tags: web3js, tokens

I need to transform stakeValue into BN, for transfer it to smartcontract

```
  const web3 = await getWeb3()
  const toBn = web3.utils.toBN.bind(web3.utils)
  const erc20Instance = await createInstance('ERC20')
  const tokenDecimals = await erc20Instance.methods.decimals().call()
  const stakeEth = toBn(stake).mul(toBn(10).pow(tokenDecimals))

  console.log(tokenDecimals) // output 18
  console.log(stake) // output 1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Iangyl! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! What's the line causing the error? Does it show a stack trace? The `num.bitLength` part is missing in the code so perhaps it is unrelated to it.

Comment: Hi Ismael! To be more accurate: the error called by pow function.

Comment: Can you check the type of tokenDecimals? Perhaps it needs to be wrapped in a BN with `toBN(tokenDecimals)`.